# any method to mix these urls in django 

Tags: python, django, url

the usl :

```
(r'^account/', include('account.urls')),
(r'^account/', include('django_authopenid.urls')),
```

i want to use these url , and  i dont want to mix it by my hand one by one ,  it is not very easy  ,

has a method to do  this  in django .

thanks

Comment: If `account.urls.urlpatterns` results in a 404, it'll keep looking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your own code can work properly in many cases, but if not you can do
this:

Create your own urls.py file:

```
from account.urls import urlpatterns as accounts_urlpatterns
from django_authopenid.urls import urlpatterns as authopenid_urlpatterns

urlpatterns = patterns("")
urlpatterns += accounts_urlpatterns
urlpatterns += authopenid_urlpatterns
```

Answer (score 2):

What you do will work, with the caveat that any pattern that would match an entry in both would be found by the first one you list.

For instance, the url `/account/openid/foo/` might match a pattern in `django_authopenid.urls` that is `r'^openid/(.*)/$'`, but that would never hit if there was a match in `account.urls` that also matched, such as `r'^(.*)/foo/$'`.